# How to sort WPF datagrid on data coming from a converter?

Tags: .net, wpf

**Question: How do I sort a datagrid on a column whose data comes from a converter?**

I have a View Model that resembles:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> Aliases { get; set; }
}
```

Further, I have a custom converter that maps the `IEnumerable<string>` to just a `string`.

My DataGrid resembles:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="...">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Width="10" Header="..." Binding="{Binding Path=Name}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Width="10" Header="..." Binding="{Binding Path=Aliases, Converter={StaticResource myConverter}}" />
     ...
```

So far, so good.  It displays as expected.  The problem comes with the sorting.

When sorting by the Name, everything is fine.  When sorting by the column whose data comes from the converter, I get a .NET exception:

> The SortDescriptions added are not valid. The probable solutions are
>   to set the CanUserSort on the Column to false, or to use
>   SortMemberPath property on the Column, or to handle the Sorting event
>   on DataGrid.

There's a solution floating around that suggests modifying the View Model to have a property that is similar to:

```
public class AliasesMapping
{
    public IEnumerable<string> Raw { get; set; }
    public string Converted { get; set; }
}
```

But... I'm wondering if there is a better or more standard approach to solving this.  It feels like in this solution, a UI limitation is bleeding into the View Model layer.

UPDATE: here's the converter

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(IEnumerable<string>), typeof(string))]
public class AliasFormatConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string converted = string.Empty;
        var val = value as IEnumerable<string>;

        if (val != null)
        {
            var list = new List<string>(val);
            list.Sort();

            converted = string.Join(",", list);
        }

        return converted;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the SortMemberPath?

Comment: I tried setting it to {Binding Path=Aliases, Converter={StaticResource myConverter}}  .. is that what you meant?

Comment: SorthMemberPath will be a path on the context, you wouldn't want to use binding on it. What happens if you set `SortMemberPath=Length`?

Comment: @Blam Done -- it's a dead simple converter though

Comment: What I would do is have a property that is the first string on that list and use that property as the for sort column (not the official name of the property but I hope you know what I am talking about)

Comment: @Blam you mean the data would look like { "all,your,base", "all", "your", "base }?  How would you set the sort column to use just the first value of the enumeration for comparison?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not tested but cannot format a comment

```
SortMemberPath="FirstString"

Public string FirtString { get { return Aliases[0]; } }
```

Not a whole lot different than the `public string Converted { get; set; }` that you want to get away from so probably not a lot of value to you.  I was just saying that is what I would try.

Comment: I have my View Models in a separate assembly from the XAML and converters.  So with this approach, I'd need to effectively move the conversion into the View Model layer?